# htaccess redirect if url have speific word

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a list of spam url generated on my website. I want to redirect these urls to homepage. These all spam urls have sale or discount word in urls.
http://www.example.com/7ukwjvo-ralph-lauren-big-sizes-sale
I want to redirect this to http://www.example.com

I have tried htaccess redirection but didn't worked

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(sale|discount)/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Please provide a solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (sale|discount)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Because with `/(sale|discount)` it only works if the word is after `/`.
And with `(sale|discount)/$` it only works if the word is before `/` in the end.

You can simply use (without `RewriteCond`):

```
RewriteRule (sale|discount)$ http://www.example.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

And you can delete the `$` to test even the words to another place that the end